# Is OpenGL threadsafe for multiple threads with distinct contexts?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, opengl-es

I know that sharing a single context between threads is bad news. I know that I can safely create and use a context with an offscreen framebuffer on a secondary thread when nothing is happening with GL on the main thread.

I haven't yet been able to find a definitive answer to the question of whether I can safely create two contexts on two different threads (say, a main thread drawing to the screen, and a secondary thread doing offscreen drawing work) and have them both making GL function calls simultaneously.

In other words, as long as the contexts are different, can two threads "share" the C API and thus the GPU? Or is that inherently something that is unshareable? Or is this implementation-specific?

Asking specifically for OpenGL ES on iOS, but it's probably a general GL question.

Comment: Related: [Should I use multiple threads within my OpenGL ES game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246189/should-i-use-multiple-threads-within-my-opengl-es-game)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to use one context for each thread you want to use OpenGL with, also you can share objects between the contexts. This is the way to go :)

Comment: Not quite correct: You don't need one context per thread, you can use the same context in more than one thread, as long as you never do so at the same time, e.g. by locking all access to the context, and as long as this locking includes a memory barrier on systems that need one (which usually is always the case for locks).

Comment: @Mecki Can you provide a reference to that notion?  Is use of a gl context __any__ invocation of a gl function?  For example, can I create a new Texture object/call `glTexImage2D` on a gl context while simultaneously drawing from the same gl context on another thread?

Comment: @bobobobo Yes, any gl* function invocation uses the currently set context for the thread; otherwise one would have to feed the desired context to every gl function. In the past OpenGL would only support one context per process, as a result contexts were made thread specific and are implicitly set for a thread today. And no, you cannot use the same context on two threads at the same time. A context can only be used by one thread at any time. You can only switch the thread a context is bound to.

Comment: @bobobobo You can bind a context to thread A, use it there, unbind it from thread A, bind it to thread B and then use it on thread B; this is allowed. If you bind a context to more than one thread and even use the context from more than one thread at the same time, the results of all gl* function calls are undefined (it may work, it may draw strange things, it may crash, whatever). Binding and unbinding are OS specific functions, they are not part of the OpenGL standard (different OSes offer different functions for this task).

Comment: @bobobobo Some OSes offer shared contexts. If contextA and contextB are shared, you can use contextA on threadA and contextB on threadB, yet the contexts share the same resource pool. So a texture created in contextA is available and can be used in contextB and the other way round. So while contextA is drawing something, contextB can load a new texture and later on contextA can use it. If you want to get a more detailed explanation or if you want to get sample code, ask an own question, after all this is what Stackoverflow is there for.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: If you don't use the context by two threads simultaneously, one context is enough.

**Option 2**: If you need to use OpenGL by several threads simultaneously, you need more than one context. Then, if the contexts share their **Sharegroup**, they share their OpenGL content like textures. This way you can load textures or do heavy framebuffer processing on a background thread.

Have a look at the last section about Sharegroups here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts.html

**Option 3**: GLKit provides some built-in background processing, for example asynchronous texture loading via `GLKTextureLoader`s `- textureWithContentsOfFile`. I don't know all the options, but it definitely simplifies some of uses cases of asynchronous OpenGL.