# Should I use multiple threads within my OpenGL ES game?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, opengl-es

I am developing an iPhone game which contains one player and many enemies.  I use OpenGL ES to display the game visuals.

I am a little confused as to whether I should only use one thread or use multiple threads for moving and controlling the player and the enemies.  What do you recommend for this basic game architecture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with Max on this one and say that you shouldn't completely ignore using multithreading in your application.  OpenGL ES can be drawn to from a background thread, but you can only communicate to an OpenGL ES context using a single thread at a time.

Apple has an entire section entitled "[Concurrency and OpenGL ES](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandOpenGLES/ConcurrencyandOpenGLES.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH409-SW2)" in their OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS.  In that, they describe several scenarios for improving performance of an OpenGL ES application using multithreading.

In general, it's recommended that you move time-consuming operations off of the main thread.  The main thread handles the user interface of your application, and if you block that you will prevent standard UI elements from updating and touch events from registering.  Depending on how much processing is being done behind the scenes for your game (physics, AI, etc.), you may need to move significant chunks of that to a background thread.

Multithreading is not a simple topic, but Apple has made this a lot easier through Grand Central Dispatch, so I highly recommend reading their [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) which describes this and other techniques for achieving multithreading in your application.  Additionally, I taught a class on multithreading and GCD as part of my course on iOS development, the video of which can be [found on iTunes U](http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/advanced-iphone-development/id407243028).

As Apple rolls out multicore devices, taking advantage of multithreading and GCD now will greatly pay off for you in the future.

Comment: I didn't say to ignore multithreading at all (read the first sentence of the second paragraph).

Comment: on conclusion ..I should use mainthread for UI controlling  and background thread for logics ,am i right?

Comment: @Ali - The main thread should be used for user interface updates not involving OpenGL ES, responding to touch events, performing other tasks that aren't thread safe (like dealing with a single Core Data context), and potentially as a synchronization point for your other processes.  I'd offload anything that takes a while to process to a background thread (again, rather than using manual threads, take a look at using GCD for this, as it will make your life a lot easier).

Comment: @BradLarson I love the `CLEAN LYRICS` rating you got on there. Despite it being iPhone programming.

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on lots of things.
First of all you won't get any performance boost if you're using several threads (since all modern iOS-devices has single core processors, though iPad2 has 2).
Second several threads make any application much more sophisticated, since you have to keep track of shared resources, synchronize threads and lots more.

Use several threads only if you really need this. For example you're loading lots of textures into memory from file and it might take several seconds. If you do this on the same thread, where there rendering is performed, then all rendering would hang for that time. So it's better to do that on a separate thread and then give loaded data to the main one. Or you might update physics on a separate thread with higher update rate (however you benefit from this only on several cores).

If you're a novice developer and making some simple game don't use multiple threads. This stuff requires lot of experience.

Comment: Just because an application is running on a single core device doesn't mean that threads are useless.  Any time-consuming action should be performed on a non-main thread to avoid blocking the UI, if possible. OpenGL ES can also be drawn to on a background thread.

Comment: @Brad Larson sorry, but did actually read what I've written? Please point me to the line, where I'm saying that threads are useless. As for multithreaded drawing: thanks, my mistake (I was sure that it is only possible to perform off-screen rendering or rendering to texture in a separate context on non-main thread)

Comment: My wording was inexact, but I was commenting on the line "you won't get any performance boost if you're using several threads" and your comment about only benefiting from performing physics calculations in a background thread on a multicore system.  You can indeed realize performance gains by multithreading tasks on a single core system, but more importantly users can perceive your application as being faster by ensuring that it is always responsive.  You make valid points about multithreading being difficult, but I don't want people to be turned away from it unnecessarily.

Comment: @Brad Larson multithreading will make app run smoothly on single core, but not faster (maybe a little due to internal processor and OS optimizations). And I don't say that we can calculate only physics on a separate thread (it was just single example). I do not discourage people to use multiple threads, however I do think it is too early for the developer that has little experience. He can't get full advantage of threading and would only bring extra mess to app. All in due time

Comment: @Brad Larson do not pay attention om comment about physics (I've read your answer wrong)

Comment: This answer is less and less relevant over time as more and more devices are multi-core. At this point I am tempted to actually downvote it.