# iOS, running openGLES on a separate thread leads to reduction in frame rate?

Tags: ios, multithreading, opengl-es, nsthread

I'm new to openGL programming and multi-threading on the iPhone and im trying to write a small openGL game and im facing a small performance issue.

The game renders Graphics as separate openGL views (I amm using ES 1.1 for now) and my rendering engine updates the graphics depending on the heading of the user (like a compass). Having gone through people's experiences online I decided to:

1. Run all openGL related operations on a separate thread (no openGL related operations between threads).
2. Run call backs from location services on the main thread
3. Use delegates to communicate heading updates between the Location Controller and my  openGLViews.

   ```
   -(void)loadGame{

   //other loading operations

   [self loadThreads];

   [graphicsThread start];

   }

   -(void)loadThreads{

   //graphics thread is an ivar          
       graphicsThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadGameViews) object:Nil];

       //load other thread related stuff

   }


   -(void)loadGameViews{

        //create and load all openGLViews


       }
   ```

EDIT :

```
 -(void)loadGameViews{

         //create and load all openGLViews
        [self.openGLView performSelector:@selector(startAnimation) onThread:graphicsThread withObject:NULL waitUntilDone:NO];

        }
```

The code works alright, but i noticed a drop in fram rate (testing on the iPad) to 40 FPS (iot was 60 while running on a single thread). 
I wanted to know:

1. If 40 FPS is an acceptable frame rate for a game.
2. If my thread logic is correct (or is there a better way to do this?)
3. If there is a way to boost my frame rate back to 60 FPS

Comment: Are you sure it's permitted to call OpenGL outside of the main thread?

Comment: I think so. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246189/should-i-use-multiple-threads-within-my-opengl-es-game

Comment: Did you try setting the "threadPriority"?