# cocos2d OpenGL error 0x0502 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers]

Tags: iphone, ios, image, image-processing, cocos2d-iphone

i have implemented [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) in my cocos2d project, The GPUImage framework is a BSD-licensed iOS library that lets you apply GPU-accelerated filters and other effects to images, live camera video, and movies.

When i call any one of GPUImage filter, am getting " cocos2d OpenGL error 0x0502 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers] " error.

Do you have any idea what might be the issue in that case?

Thanks and regards, Prakash.

Comment: 0x0502 stands for `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. Are you trying to use a texture from GPUImage with cocos2d? The two by default will have different OpenGL ES contexts, so you won't be able to use a texture from one in the other, unless you set up sharing between the contexts. I'm not familiar with cocos2d and how it does its context initialization, but somehow you'll need to set up a share group between the GPUImage and cocos2d contexts.

Comment: @BradLarson am using this two line only in my coco2d class ------                   GPUImageToonFilter *stillImageFilter2 = [[GPUImageToonFilter alloc] init];
    image = [stillImageFilter2 imageByFilteringImage:image];------- after executing this two line an getting this error

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what your code is doing but what i had seen is that some time swap buffer problems come if their is change in orientation of application from the normal orientation.Try to print the size of main view before and after using your code.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have the same problem. I found the following post useful:
[iOS and multiple OpenGL views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111345/ios-and-multiple-opengl-views)

In my case, cocos2d files don't have necessary "setCurrentContext" commands ,so I added it into CCEAGLView-ios.mm. It solves my problem.

```
(void) layoutSubviews
{
[renderer_ resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
size_ = [renderer_ backingSize];

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext: context_];
cocos2d::Size size;
size.width = size_.width;
size.height = size_.height;

cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->drawScene();
}
```