# cocos2d: animation stopped. Integrate Cocos2D and UIKit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I already integrate Cocos2D and UIKit. 
I have the navigation among the views and the first time that I open the cocos view, it works.
But when I return to my main menu, the log console displays:

```
cocos2d: animation stopped
```

After that, if I try to get in to the cocos2D view again, the animation does not start.

What can I do to solve this?

I followed this tutorial but it don´t help
http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit

Comment: did you call startAnimation on director upon returning to the cocos2d view? If not, do that.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks a lot!  I haven´t it

Answer (score 0):

There have been issues regarding this. There was a [similar discussion in another SO Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168079/multiple-opengl-views-cocos2d)

Whenever I want to include UIKit elements, I tend to do it the other way round.

With the CCUIViewWrapper code at: https://github.com/splhack/CCUIViewWrapper

Answer (score 0):

This maybe be different depending on the version of cocos2d you are using, but `stopAnimation` should be being called on `CCDirectorIOS.m:viewDidDisappear` and `startAnimation` should be being called on `viewWillAppear`. So I would set breakpoints there to make sure it is being called on. And if your `-(void) mainLoop:(id)sender` is running.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self startAnimation];
}

-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [self stopAnimation];

  [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

If you want to investigate further the mainLoop calls drawScene and if it is not `isPaused`, then the CCScheduler will update the CCActionManager which runs all of the animations.

Hope this helps.